# How to tearDown() mockObjects in PHP unit

Tags: php, docker, zend-framework, phpunit, docker-compose

I have to test a controller in php, where it uses more than 20 models. When I tried to create the mocks for the models using prophecy it fails with the

> Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size Exhausted

I tried to increase the memory_limit in php.ini too, it is not solving the issue. I couldn't find a way to clear the memory used by the mockModels which will solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an endless loop between your models?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ there is no loop in the models

Comment: As you can see here: [https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/2f789b59ab89669015ad984afa350c4ec577ade0/src/Generator.php#L154] phpUnit mock builder using ReflectionClass to mock objects. That's why i asked if there's a endless loop between objects.

Also before php 5.3 there's always a possibility for memory leak.